# Group the rows and display All values in GROUPS

Tags: mysql, database, group-by

My Table structure looks like:

```
ID sub_id Score 
1  12      1
2  13      3
3  11      1
4  12      5
5  12      7
6  13      2
```

I want to arrange it

```
ID sub_id Score 
3  11      1
1  12      1
4  12      5
5  12      7
6  13      2
2  13      3
```

I want to group based on sub_ids and order by score of each sub_ids. I am trying to sort data based on sub_id group

Comment: That's not grouping, that's ordering, so use the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Are you trying to actually change data, or just sort it?

Comment: Why are the IDs moving to different rows when you reorder them?

Comment: It seems like you want to modify ID value, which is not a smart idea. What about simple reordering, using `ORDER BY` clause in your request.

Comment: Sorry I am not modifying ID. Just sort the data based on score but group it based on sub_ids. Eg Sort score for sub_id=11 , sort for sub_id=12 and 13 similarly and display it in groups. Sorry I was not able to format table correctly.

Comment: Ok it looked like you where an Primary Key neat freak, can you try to fix the example because it makes no sense now what you want..

Comment: Sorry I edited the table. @RaymondNijland Let me know if it makes sense now. Thank you

Comment: Np the answers below are already correct and could give you the result you need

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I appreciate it. Sorry about the confusion.Answer by @Steve worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to order the data by sub_id and then by Score:

```
SELECT * FROM [tbl_name] ORDER BY sub_id, Score
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple matter of using order by:

```
select * from yourtable order by sub_id
```